# the user is forced to authorize my app each time

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, tweepy

I am using tweepy api for oauth: http://packages.python.org/tweepy/html/auth_tutorial.html#oauth-authentication

The first time, user is ask to authorize my app. But from the second time, I dont want the user to be asked to authorize my app again.

### The tutorial says

It is a good idea to save the access token for later use. You do not need to re-fetch it each time. Twitter currently does not expire the tokens, so the only time it would ever go invalid is if the user revokes our application access. To store the access token depends on your application. Basically you need to store 2 string values: key and secret:

auth.access_token.key

auth.access_token.secret

---

I plan to store access_token key and secret to a session. When user use my app the second time, I will just use the access_token, so user will not be forced to authorize my app again.

However, THE PROBLEM IS that what happen when many twitter users use my app, how can I know which access_token belong to which user.

I hope my question is clear.

1. Stop twitter to force user to authorize my app from second time.
2. if I need to store access_token to solve (1), how can I know which access_token belong to which user.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement session management in your web app and associate session IDs with your user model which stores the auth information. You don't say what language you are using but if you use the Ruby on Rails framework then session management is easily done. I recommend the Devise gem with omniauth-twitter (https://github.com/arunagw/omniauth-twitter).

Comment: He's using Tweepy, it means that he is trying to solve a problem using Python.